# How to define a specific version of macOS in C

Tags: c, macos, makefile

We can use `#ifdef _linux_` or `#ifdef __APPLE__` to identify the user's operating system. But can we define different versions of the operating system? For example between macOS Big Sur and macOS Monterey.

In search of an answer, I came across the [Availability.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.18.24/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/Availability.h.auto.html) library, but I didn't quite understand how to find the right version of OS

Comment: Do you want to test for the OS version under which the code was compiled, or the minimum OS version that the compiled code should run on, or the actual OS version that the compiled code IS running on?  Those are 3 different questions, and the 3rd one can't be answered using preprocessor tests.

Comment: @JWWalker My program should work differently on macOS Monterey, unlike all other versions of macOS. I need to make that only on macOS Monterey the function code will work differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test for the OS at runtime in C/C++ code like so:

```cpp
if (__builtin_available( macOS 12.0, * ))
{
    // Monterey or later
}
else
{
    // before Monterey
}
```

Of course you'll have to think about what should happen when macOS 13 comes out.

Comment: I feel bad for the authors of tools that parse C code now. I don't think I've ever seen such an atrociously non-C syntax in a C extension for no good reason before.

Comment: This will throw a syntax error for any compiler other than Clang.  Unless you don't care about portability you should avoid it.

Comment: @MadScientist If you're writing code specifically for macOS, then you are very likely using Xcode, so you are using Clang.

Comment: Sure, but the first sentence of the question discusses using preprocessor queries for Linux so I thought I would mention that if you use this solution you will be required to use clang, even on Linux.